# A weird possibly Italian horror film I only got to see the end of it

Tags: story-identification, horror, zombie

The series of events didn't make sense but what I saw still perplexes me years afterwards..

1. A man is getting dressed and leaving a bedroom after what seems a one night stand. The woman is still in bed and drowsily asks the man to turn the heater up because it's so cold. He not only turns the portable heater up, he places it right on her bed and under her blanket. Unaware of what he's done, she thanks him before she falls asleep. As he leaves her apartment (flat?) he looks over his shoulder briskly to see flames flare up through a window.
2. There's some zombies ... I can't remember what happened, I was very sick.
3. I woke up to see the end. There was that man from the previous scene and a bigger man with him. I think the bigger man had a shovel. They were looking out to the horizon at  dawn. It looked like they were on a mountain or cliff maybe?

I saw this movie in the late 90s I believe. I think it might've been Italian or at least European. Either it was dubbed or the Nyquil I took was making me really loopy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're describing the Italian-French-German horror comedy [Cemetery Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cemetery_Man), (1994), original title "Dellamorte Dellamore".

> The film's story concerns the beleaguered caretaker of a small Italian
>   cemetery, who searches for love while defending himself from dead
>   people who keep rising again.
>
> ...
>
> Dellamorte doesn't want to lose the job. He opens up to his only
>   friend, Franco, a municipal clerk, but doesn't file the paperwork
>   necessary to get assistance: "It's easier just to shoot them."

He also keeps encountering different "manifestations" of his love interest, different women all played by the same actress, Anna Falchi.

> He meets a third manifestation of the woman he loves, but upon finding
>   out that she is a prostitute, he kills her and two other women by
>   setting their house on fire with a room heater.

The movie does end with Dellamorte and his assistant Gnaghi, a "bigger man", standing on a cliff:

> Gnaghi and the caretaker pack up the car, and head for the Buffalora
>   city limits and the mountains beyond. Gnaghi's head is injured when
>   Dellamorte slams on the brakes. They get out of the vehicle and walk
>   to the edge of the road, where it drops into a chasm.

Comment: Spot on Mr. Feldman! That movie has haunted me for years. So it wasn't the Nyquil giving me hallucinations. Thank you, sir! :)

Comment: Note that the movie is based on a novel by Tiziano Sclavi, author of the comic book Dylan Dog, whose namesake character eerily resembles Rupert Everett. It so happens that Rupert Everett plays the role of the caretaker...